# $_SESSION function not working

Tags: php, session

I want to send parameters with $_SESSION. 
this my code --

```
if(isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
        $username = "testing";
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        header('Location: admin.php');
```

and i want to recive it on different page, my second code --

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION["username"];
echo "hello, $user" ?>
```

i get this massege -- 
Notice: Undefined index: username in Line 33 ($user = $_SESSION["username"];)

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION))` that's wrong; you need to check if it is *not* set.

Comment: Hey, i update my post, please look again !

Comment: Its still `isset` put the not operator to make it work